# Listing files in a directory, where the filename matches a regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, meteor

I want to get all filenames within a directory that follow a specific pattern. I found out, that I can accomplish this by doing the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir( dir, function(err, list) {
    if(err)
        throw err;
    var regex = new RegExp(".*");
    list.forEach( function(item) {
    if( regex.test(item) ) 
       console.log(item);
    }); 
});
```

I was wondering, if there is another possibility to do this without using a loop, e.g. passing a regex to `fs.readdir(..)`.
Is that somehow possible, or do I have to use a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`npm` atmosphere package](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm) to use other NPM modules. This will let you use the popular [`glob` NPM module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/glob). This uses glob patterns, which are more common for matching file names than regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the function [`fs.readdir`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) does not take a regular expression to filter file names before calling the callback. It mentions explicitly using `readdir(3)` which has no notion of regular expression.

So you have to loop through the results and filter them. Or perhaps use a 3rd party library that would do it for you but `fs.readdir` won't by itself do it.